# Name Error- name "xxxxx" is not defined with the objects - Python

Tags: python

Am very new to Python programming.Which am getting the naming error in my function with the object but without the object it works fine.

Hope to get a help from the community.

```
--Code works
def determine_grade(TestScore):
     print("test")
def Mainfunction():
     test1 = float(input('Enter the score for test 1: '))
     print("Your Grade for Test 1 is : ",determine_grade(test1))
Mainfunction() 

--Code doesnot works

class clsCalcScore_Ex6(object):

def determine_grade(TestScore):
     print("test")
def Mainfunction():
     test1 = float(input('Enter the score for test 1: '))
     print("Your Grade for Test 1 is : ",determine_grade(test1))
Mainfunction(object)
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. There are many things wrong here and it would be best if you carefully follow a tutorial instead. As a refresher, though, please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We are not interested in your level of expertise; we *are* interested in a clearly asked *question* (starting with a question word like 'how' or 'why' and ending with a `?`), your [attempt to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and [complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal problem with your code is that your definition of the class `clsCalcScore_Ex6` is incomplete.  If you add a single line to fully define the class, like this, your code will work:

```
class clsCalcScore_Ex6(object):
    pass
```

If what you want to do is move your functions into the class as methods, then you have more work to do. Here's what doing that correctly might look like:

```
class clsCalcScore_Ex6(object):

    def determine_grade(self, TestScore):
         print("test")

    def Mainfunction(self):
         test1 = float(input('Enter the score for test 1: '))
         print("Your Grade for Test 1 is : ", self.determine_grade(test1))

clsCalcScore_Ex6().Mainfunction()
```

Here's another way that uses static methods and avoids you having to instantiate an instance of the class (note the removal of the first set of parens in the last line):

```
class clsCalcScore_Ex6(object):

    @staticmethod
    def determine_grade(TestScore):
         print("test")

    @staticmethod
    def Mainfunction():
         test1 = float(input('Enter the score for test 1: '))
         print("Your Grade for Test 1 is : ", clsCalcScore_Ex6.determine_grade(test1))

clsCalcScore_Ex6.Mainfunction()
```

The second way is functionally identical to your original code.  It just adds a namespace, placing most of your code under the name `clsCalcScore_Ex6`.